# Why armeabi-v7a conflicts with armeabi of another module?

Tags: android, module, native

I have 2 modules in my project

Moudle 1:

- `libs/armeabi`

Module 2:

- `libs/armeabi`
- `libs/armeabi-v7a`

In order to successfully run the app, I have to remove `armeabi-v7a` folder completely, otherwise the `.so` libs in `Module 1` `armeabi` folder won't load

Why ?

Answer (score 1):

During app installation, **either** `armeabi` **or** `armeabi-v7a` libs will be extracted from the APK. In this scenario, you would hope Android chooses the `armeabi` libs, but on `armeabi-v7a` devices, it will install `armeabi-v7a` libs, since at least one exists.

If you are going to include libs for multiple ABIs then you must include all libs for all those ABIs.